# MongoDB JDBC select sub document syntax

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, coldfusion

I am using Progree DirectData drivers in coldfusion 11 and I can return data using a simple `select * from accounts`.

I can see in RoboMongo that there are sub documents, however I can't work out how to select the sub document as it's not coming up.

[image: coldfusion select query]

[image: Robomongo shows sub documents]

Comment: Please post code as **text** in a code block, not as an image.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document in the BSON/JSON form?